# New line in "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-2" email body type

Tags: java, email, outlook, newline, plaintext

I need new line to divide email body in two sections which are written in various languages.

Already tried:

- doubled windows new line  + `"\r\n\r\n"` +
- extra tab before new line + `"\t"` +
- java system independent new line property + `System.getProperty("line.separator")` +
- combined above + `"\t"` + `System.getProperty("line.separator")` +

Somehow Outlook ignores all.
I've searched stackoverflow and haven't found the answer, would be great if somebody knows the solution.

PS I can't change body type into text/html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution of my problem, double tab do the trick + "\t\t" +
Whenever you need new line in the email body of type "text/plain" just simply append double tab.

Answer (score 0):

### [Line breaks are removed in posts made in plain text format in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287816)

> Use one of the following methods to work around this behavior:
>   Method 1. Disable (in Outlook) the feature that removes extra line breaks
>   Method 2. Use HTML or Rich Text format
>   Method 3. Restore the line breaks in Outlook 2003 or Outlook 2002

Comment: I can't do anything with Outlook, emails are sent to customers. 
I can't change body type it has to stay "text/plain" because i use some common peace of code.  

My job is to do it right for any kind of email client.  

PS IF whole body message is stored in DB, new line is interpreted by Outlook correctly.